# How to add a BPMN, DMN and CMMN to Camunda running on jboss

Tags: process, jboss, bpmn, camunda

I'm new to camunda and this kind of software. I'm doing a research on Case Management Fameworks and am currently trying out camunda in order to obtain information on how to use etc. I created a BPMN, DMN and CMMN with Camunda Modeler and want to implement it in Camunda. 
Camunda is Running on Jboss since it didn't work on apache for some reason. The camunda website only offers instruction when using apache.

The method to implement these processes in camunda is very vague to me and I don't get it at all. Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You must copy your application to the folder

> $CAMUNDA_HOME/server/wildfly-VERSION/standalone/deployments

You can find a complete step-for-step example for Java EE 7 and JBoss here:
https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/javaee6/

Comment: Ah oke thanks, That's one step further. The only thing that's still not clear is creating a .war file: "select the pom.xml in the Package Explorer" Which one and where? There are multiple in random folders when using the search function. Perform a right-click and select Run As / Maven Clean and afterwards Run As / Maven Install." I guess I have to install this software called "Maven" in order to do this?

Comment: You will develop a Java EE Application? Embedded Maven is a part of eclipse. Maven is an essential part of the Java EE development. What is your Goal?

Comment: Yeah I just figured out this basically requires a understanding of Java Application server which I don't have... The original idea was to create a process in the modeler and make it run camunda. The goal was to do this in order to understand how camunda works with case management and get a better picture of casemanagement in general.

Comment: Yes, camunda isn't a zero-coding engine. Without Java development know-how, it is very difficult to achieve the goal.